# Eliminar o cambiar Footer

Tags: html

Estoy editando una pagina en blogger pero en el `footer` hay como "una marca de agua" por así decirlo. El texto dice 'Diseñado Por Free Blogger Templates'
Y ya lo modifique en HTML y le cambie el enlace y todo, pero sigue apareciendo eso. Lo intente eliminar pero cuando abro la pagina, me redirige a otra.

**¿Debe de haber una manera de eliminar eso no?** Para no comprar el tema, algún `script` o algo.

Aqui les dejo el codigo ya que es largo:

### Busquen el codigo: [Ver codigo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qw3gbubpcc5p98/Issac.xml?dl=0)

```
<footer class='contactFooter'>
    <div class='container'>
      <!-- COPYRIGHT -->
      <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 footerLeft'>
        Design By <a herf='http://www.templateclue.com/' href='http://www.templateclue.com/' id='templateclue' ref='dofollow' title='Free Blogger Templates'>Free Blogger Templates</a> &amp; <a href="http://mybloggerthemes.com" rel="dofollow" style="color: #c49b66;" title="Blogger Template">MyBloggerThemes</a>
      </div>
      <!-- SOCIAL ICONS -->

    </div>
    <!-- END container-->
  </footer>
```

---

La verdad no se si se puede, pero uds saben mas.

Comment: link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qw3gbubpcc5p98/Issac.xml?dl=0

Comment: Se publico mal, busquen el codigo: <footer class='contactFooter'>
    <div class='container'>
      <!-- COPYRIGHT -->
      <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 footerLeft'>
        Design By <a herf='http://www.templateclue.com/' href='http://www.templateclue.com/' id='templateclue' ref='dofollow' title='Free Blogger Templates'>Free Blogger Templates</a> &amp; <a href="http://mybloggerthemes.com" rel="dofollow" style="color: #c49b66;" title="Blogger Template">MyBloggerThemes</a>
      </div>
      <!-- SOCIAL ICONS -->

    </div>
    <!-- END container-->
  </footer>

Comment: Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/86807/edit) y corregir lo que se ha publicado mal, en vez de ponerlo en comentario.

Comment: en la nueva version no es posible

Answer (score 1):

Esto es muy simple:

```
<div class="contactFooter">
<div class="container">
<!-- copyright -->
 <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 footerLeft'>
   <!-- El texto que estaba dentro de este DIV hacia que miraras esa "marca de agua" -->
  </div>
```

```
</div>
<!-- END container-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez un `remove()` de JS sirva:

```js
function quitarFooter(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].remove();
  
  //No importante 
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].remove();
  document.body.innerHTML = "footer removido!!";
}
```

```html
<footer class='contactFooter'>
    <div class='container'>
      <!-- COPYRIGHT -->
      <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 footerLeft'>
        Design By <a herf='http://www.templateclue.com/' href='http://www.templateclue.com/' id='templateclue' ref='dofollow' title='Free Blogger Templates'>Free Blogger Templates</a> &amp; <a href="http://mybloggerthemes.com" rel="dofollow" style="color: #c49b66;" title="Blogger Template">MyBloggerThemes</a>
      </div>
      <!-- SOCIAL ICONS -->

    </div>
    <!-- END container-->
  </footer>
  
  <!-- No importante -->
  <input type="button" onclick="quitarFooter()" value="Adiós footer"/>
```